# Disk space problem while installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted

I have encountered a problem while installing Ubuntu 14.04 modified for it@school educational purposes. I have a Windows 7 PC running and have enough space with both NTFS and Unallocated. But I have been getting a problem as there is not enough space (19.8GB) so that I can't proceed, but I still have the space for the installation. My System is in Legacy mode and its have total 3 partitions and one is unallocated as shown in screenshots,Here are the screenshots.

[Screenshot 1 - Disk partiotion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g19B8.jpg)

[Screenshot 2 - Ubuntu Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlDFh.jpg)

Comment: When you're at the live session open Gparted. Please post a screenshot showing how it sees your drive. Now you have enough unallocated space and less than 4 primary partitions so it should work unless you're using "dynamic disks" in Windows which renders the drive unreadable from Linux (the technology is Microsoft proprietary).

Comment: Hello Sir, I think it may be problem with windows 10,then i reinstalled it to windows 7 yesterday but no luck, so i checked with Gparted and here i am attaching an drive link for the screenshots, please review and help me. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2plKfjxLkgqNTFITFlKbnlkY2s?usp=sharing